# Hot Reload not working for my flutter app in vscode

Tags: flutter, hot-reload

I am developing a Flutter app with local packages, and I am facing an issue where changes made to a package do not reflect in the app even after running hot reload or hot restart. My app structure includes multiple local packages, and I have added them to my app's pubspec.yaml file as dependencies with the correct version numbers.

I am running the app in debug mode using a launch.json file, and I have also tried running the app using the "flutter run" command in the terminal, but the issue persists.

I have checked that the packages are being imported and used correctly in my code, and I have also tried flutter clean and running the app again, but the changes still don't reflect.

Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to fix this issue? I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *with the correct version numbers* - note that local packages should simply be imported with the `path` directive - and that there is then no "version numbering" involved - you get, in the main app, what's on the local disk of the local subpackage.

Answer (score 0):

When running you app from vscode, make sure you see "Debug My Code + Packages" + sdk (optional). If not, click there and you will see it.

Also, after making change in the package (local or from pub.dev), make sure to save the current file in current project. It triggers hot-reload with all the relevant changes from another packages.

[image]

Comment: i see the exact same thing, and hot restart also running, and the app is also refreshing. The only thing is changes not appeared until i close the project and restart it again